# Altium designer component links

Tags: pcb, components, altium, designer

I drew a simple design with few capacitors just to learn how component links work in altium desginer. (Image 2, pic a)

I checked manualy one by one all capacitors and I saw that UIDs are matched with pcb document. (Image 1, pic a)
In Project -> component links -> Perform Update, a message popup "component links are up to date" appeared.

I tried to change the designators of my schematic between two components. (Image 2 pic b)
After I executed the changes on pcb document I checked again their UIDs manually. I saw again that the UIDs are still matched correctly. (Image 1 pic b)

However, when I hit again, Project -> Component Links... -> Perform Update, a message inform me that "Component links modified in... 2 Links modified"
Which are those two links and how were they modified? The UIDs seemed to be matched even before I perform update.

Can someone explain that to me?[image]

Comment: I think it would just be updating the designator field in the link? The component links functionality has always been a little bit of a beast you need to respect, but if you don't do anything too crazy it seems to almost always turn out right.

Comment: The real tell of if it broke something is when you go to sync the sheets, if it requests unexpected component changes as part of the update. Then you need to go back and make sure you've not done something stupid when messing around with the links.

Comment: As I mentioned above, after changing the designators and perform changes through Engineering Change Order dialog, the corresponding parts have updated UIDs that are matched with the schematic. See the photos.

Comment: Um, it looks like you just changed the designator in the schematic and the UIDs did not change? That's the way it's supposed to work so it can track components when their properties are edited.

Comment: @Daniel, Yes but the question was: Why, when I press Project -> component links -> Perform Update, I see the message "Component links modified in... 2 Links modified"? Considering UIDs unchanged, links should not be modified as the message says, or do they?

Comment: I think the link uses a combination key that includes the reference designator. I don't know. If you want a definitive answer you should contact Altium support.